# Setup an oozie that stops after a few runs

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

I need to setup an Oozie job that runs every 1 hour from 9am till 5pm and then stop for the day. And then do the same for all week days. I know how to set up something that starts at a given time and does that, but not able to figure out how to make it stop at 5pm. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that, Oozie frequency syntax is no different from Crontab. So, I did something like this to make it happen.

```
frequency="00 09-17 * * *"
```

Comment: The only notable difference is the missing seconds field: https://oozie.apache.org/docs/5.2.0/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a4.4.4._Cron_syntax_in_coordinator_frequency